Auto Rig Pro Quick Rig is being wonky
I’ve been using Quick rig on Auto Rig Pro for a while now and I haven’t had this issue yet. Whenever I try to do quick rig on this model, I always get an error in response. When I try to do it again after, it says that the spine is missing input bones. I redo the spine entirely, and then it says the head is missing input bones. It keeps doing this for every new limb that gets puished to the top of the window. Somebody please help I’m not sure what’s wrong with this thing.



